# JPQL union of two joins

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I have two related entities, User and Message. 
Message has two field containing the User entity, recipient and sender.

Can I do something like union of two joins, where I get the users from both fields of Message to one result list?

For example:

```
(select u from Message m join m.recipient) union (select u from Message m join m.sender)
```

Thanks for answers.

Regards

Piotr Kozlowski

Comment: [eclipselink supports `UNION`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#UNION), but if you want to stick with standards then I suspect you'll have to run two queries.

Answer (score 6):

No. But you can use a query like

```
select u from User u 
where u.id in (select m.recipient.id from Message m)
or u.id in (select m.sender.id from Message m)
```